# Finding images not referenced in a DB table

Tags: coldfusion

I get a query of all the files (images) in a directory

```
<cfset local.teamBase = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())#teamlogo\">
<cfdirectory action="LIST" directory="#local.teamBase#" name="rc.qryTeamLogo">
```

I later loop over all these filenames, skipping those that are in use

```
   <select name="Logo" <cfif deleted>disabled="disabled"</cfif>>
      <option></option>
      <cfloop query="rc.qryTeamLogo">
         <cfif name EQ mylogo>
            <option value="#name#" selected>#name#</option> 
         <cfelseif request.objTeam.isUsed(name) EQ 1 OR name EQ "thumbs.db">
            <!--- Do not show --->
         <cfelse>
            <option value="#name#">#name#</option>  
         </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </select>
```

The `isUsed()` function looks like

```
<cffunction name="isUsed"  returntype="boolean" output="false">
<cfargument name="logo" required="true" type="string">

      <cfquery name="qryUsed" datasource="#application.DSN#">
         SELECT logo
         FROM   CCF.team
         WHERE  logo = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#arguments.logo#">
         AND        Deleted = 0
    </cfquery>

    <cfif qryUsed.recordcount EQ 0>
        <cfreturn false>
    </cfif> 

    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

The problem with this is as more and more files get added, this gets slower and slower.

What I would really like a single query that can assemble the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run one query before your `select` box

```
<cfquery name="qryLogos" datasource="#application.DSN#">
SELECT logo
FROM CCF.team
WHERE logo IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#valueList(rc.qryTeamLogo.name)#" list="true">)
AND Deleted = 0
</cfquery>
```

Then set all those logo's into an array and add thumbs.db too, so you have one less check to do.

```
<cfset allLogs = listToArray(valueList(qryLogos.logo))>
<cfset arrayAppend(allLogs,'thumbs.db')>
```

and then change your elseif to this

```
<cfelseif arrayFind(allLogs,name)>
  <!--- don't display --->
```

Comment: I do not know how many values we are talking about here, but just keep in mind there are also limits on how many value an `IN` clause will accept (database dependent). An `IN` clause is better suited to small lists of values. Once you get beyond a certain point, the table based join approach usually provides better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file information into XML. Shread the XML into a table and JOIN on that.

```
<cfset  local.teamBase = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())#teamlogo\">

<cfset  local.qryTeamLogo = DirectoryList(local.teamBase, false, "query")>

<cfsavecontent variable="local.xmlTeamLogo">    
<ul class="xoxo">
    <cfoutput query="local.qryTeamLogo">    
        <li><code>#xmlformat(name)#</code></li>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
</cfsavecontent>


<cfquery name="local.qryResult">
    DECLARE @xmlTeamLogo xml = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_varchar" value="#local.xmlTeamLogo#">

    SELECT Value AS Name
    FROM dbo.udfXOXORead(@xmlTeamLogo)
    WHERE   NOT Value IN    (
        SELECT  Logo
        FROM    CCF.Team WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE   Deleted = 0
        )
</cfquery>
```

**The Table Valued Function**

```
create function [dbo].[udfXOXORead](@xmlData xml)

returns @tblmessage TABLE (
    [value]     nvarchar(max) NULL
    )
as
begin
  INSERT INTO @tblMessage

  SELECT Tbl.Col.value('(code)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')        AS [value]
  FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ul/li') Tbl(Col)

RETURN
end
```